# Teensy-weensy FAQ Edit Request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I know this sounds silly, but can a mod please update the FAQ and capitalize "Illustration"?

> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - illustration
> - Digital media
> - Examples: video, Adobe Flash

I realize it's a 1-letter edit, but this list is always visible, front and center at the top of the FAQ...

Comment: Fixed. Good catch, Hawkeye. :-)

Comment: @Alan Thank you kindly, Mister.  And if you wouldn't mind throwing a "status-completed" tag and answer on this guy,  we can close & bury it...

Comment: A soul after my own nitpicking heart. I salute you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incredibly arduous editing marathon is now done. :-D All my jobs should be so easy...

Comment: They should all be so easy...  but pay much better.  ;)

Comment: Right on, brother!